# Refresh data mondrian cube

Tags: refresh, pentaho, mondrian

In which way is possible to increase the refresh rate of the data in a Mondrian cube?

My DwH is uploaded every 15 minutes, and I need to obtain the fresh data on the Pentaho Analyzer Report

Thanks
Nico

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, the only way to refresh the mondrian cache in Pentaho is using the console or the [cache apis of mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/cache_control.php).

Or, seen that your DWH refresh rate is so low, you can [disable the cache entirely](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?78411-How-to-disable-Mondrian-s-cache)